# Is there a generalization of Polya urns to continuous outcome event?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Take for example the simplest model where there are n blue balls and m white balls in an urn. Then, in a first step realization, a white one has been drawn and then c + 1 of this colour had been put back.

This can be thought as drawing from a $Bi(1,\frac{m}{m+n})$ and then updating the next sampling distribution to a $Bi(1,\frac{m+c}{m+n+c})$. So, you can think of the entire process as a series of discrete random distributions which are determined by the realizations of previous random variables.

My question is: has been studied a generalization in which the draw is made from a continuous distribution and, then, it is updated to a new (continuous) distribution according to a pre-set rule?

My interest would be to know at time 0 the distribution of possible outcomes at t, knowing how distributions evolve conditionally to previous outcomes.

Furthermore, if this kind of preceses had been studied, does it has been further generalized to continuous time?

The most comprehensive study of this kind of processes I found is this: Mahmoud's 'Polya Urn Models' which doesn't adress my question (though it is an outstandig book covering the subject).

If any references to this respect can be found, I would be really thankful

Comment: N. Makarov talked about trying to formalize the following: Start with a compact subset of the plane, and let a small particle drift in from infinity under Brownian motion. Let it stick where it first hits, and add it to the set. Then release another particle, etc. Take a limit of this process as the size of the particle goes to 0. This is similar to a Pólya urn model because the harmonic measure may tend to expand where the particle hits. I believe he proposed it as a problem worthy of study.